# How many XP orbs are needed to restore 1 durability point?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm on MCBE 1.16 and my tools aren't repairing fast, even though I have Mending on them. How many XP orbs are needed to restore 1 durability point on my items, and what is the best way I can repair them?

Comment: Do you have mending?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have Mending, **one XP orb restores ***2*** durability points.** A simple way to mend a tool without using dual wielding requires a manual gold farm. You hold the item that needs to be repaired, and hit the pigmen with the item. Though it consumes durability, more durability will be restored than taken. I hope this helps.